# Jquery slide plugins

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

there are several questions like this, but none of the answers worked for me.

this happens on my site as well, when i set the direction left/right/whatever, it just shows from the up left corner no matter what i do.

i think the problem is with jquery ui... i downloaded it, i linked it, still not working. maybe it's the order of including?

can someone tell me the minimum of jquery ui i need for functions like these? (and how to get this work).

thanks a lot

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6sdaf7h/) `<-- here's the JSfiddle`

Comment: What do you expect us to do with an _empty_ fiddle?

Comment: please set up a fiddle

Comment: sorry, i forgot to hit save in fiddle when i copied it. fixed it now

Comment: I looked around and maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/2/) can help you out. Take a loot and come back to me.

Comment: yeah, i saw this, and used it that way... not working :( as i said, it could be because of the jquery-ui, though i linked all of it after not being able to figure out which file i have to use. still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a snipped for you below.
What I did was follow the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/2/) that I provided in the comments.
By making everything apart from each other and include the needed libraries.
I don't *exactly* know what went wrong with your code but I hope this helps you further.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var menu = $('#menu');
  var nav = $('#nav');

  menu.click(function() {
    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = {
      direction: 'right'
    };
    var duration = 300;
    $('#nav').toggle(effect, options, duration);
  });

});
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
#nav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id='menu'></div>
<div id='nav'></div>
```

Comment: ^_^ yeah. i'll copy your links to jqueru. thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! Goodluck with your project and have a nice day